# Didn't creating kiali ingress resource after kiali deployment

Tags: kubernetes, istio, nginx-ingress, kiali, istio-kiali

I deployed the kiali-operator helm chart in the kiali-operator namespace and istio in the istio-system namespace. Now I am trying to deploy the kiali workload in the istio-system.
But somehow ingress rule did not create. I attached the kiali deployment YAML file for reference.

```html
apiVersion: kiali.io/v1alpha1
kind: Kiali
metadata:
  name: kiali
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  istio_labels:
      app_label_name: "app.kubernetes.io/name"
  installation_tag: "kiali"

  istio_namespace: "istio-system"

  version: "default"
  auth:
    strategy: token

  custom_dashboards:
  - name: "envoy"
  deployment:
    accessible_namespaces: ["**"]
    ingress:
      # default: additional_labels is empty
      # additional_labels:
      #   ingressAdditionalLabel: "ingressAdditionalLabelValue"
      class_name: "nginx"
      default: enabled is undefined
      enabled: true
      # default: override_yaml is undefined
      override_yaml:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
            nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
        spec:
          rules:
          - http:
              paths:
              - path: "/kiali"
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:  
                    name: "kiali"
                    port: 
                      number: 20001
    instance_name: "kiali"
    
  external_services:
    custom_dashboards:
        enabled: true
    istio:
      component_status:
        components:
        - app_label: "istiod"
          is_core: true
          is_proxy: false
        - app_label: "istio-ingressgateway"
          is_core: true
          is_proxy: true
          # default: namespace is undefined
          namespace: istio-system
        - app_label: "istio-egressgateway"
          is_core: false
          is_proxy: true
          # default: namespace is undefined
          namespace: istio-system
        enabled: true
      config_map_name: "istio"
      envoy_admin_local_port: 15000
      # default: istio_canary_revision is undefined
      istio_canary_revision:
        current: "1-9-9"
        upgrade: "1-10-2"
      istio_identity_domain: "svc.cluster.local"
      istio_injection_annotation: "sidecar.istio.io/inject"
      istio_sidecar_annotation: "sidecar.istio.io/status"
      istio_sidecar_injector_config_map_name: "istio-sidecar-injector"
      istiod_deployment_name: "istiod"
      istiod_pod_monitoring_port: 15014
      root_namespace: ""
      url_service_version: ""
    prometheus:
      # Prometheus service name is "metrics" and is in the "telemetry" namespace
      url: "<prome_url>"
    grafana:
      auth:
        ca_file: ""
        insecure_skip_verify: false
        password: "password"
        token: ""
        type: "basic"
        use_kiali_token: false
        username: "user"
      enabled: true
      # Grafana service name is "grafana" and is in the "telemetry" namespace.
      in_cluster_url: '<grafana_url>'
      url: '<grafana_url>'
    tracing:
      enabled: true
      in_cluster_url: '<jaeger-url>'
      use_grpc: true
```

Advance thanks for any help!!

Comment: that's normal nginx ingress you can create it manually also for ref what error are you noticing ? checked logs ?

Comment: @HarshManvar That manually ingress part I aware of that. But kiali is providing an inbuilt configuration for ingress, But it is not working.